# How does VSCode ensure that all node dependencies are installed for extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to build a pluggable application myself and was wondering how vscode manages the extensions' dependencies. Does it `npm install` in each extension directory and just use those? Or does it have some global scope where each dependency is only loaded once into the runtime and reused?

The reason why I ask is because I want to make the mechanism as fast and efficient as I can currently do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code loads and runs extensions in a separate process called extension host which is a node.js process. The dependencies from `package.json` are installed during the packaging of the extension and each extension uses its own copy of the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does each extension get its own extension host process? Sorry if I am annoying but how would the extension host process communicate with the main process of electron? I found some code under `vs/workbench/node/` that has something to do with the extensions. Looks like it is the installing process.

Comment: May I ask what the advantage of loading the extensions in their own process has?

Comment: Isolation. Extensions can not affect each other or the main editor. Editor does not get affected from any performance issues or crash that extensions can suffer from.

Comment: One last question: Does VSCode use one node process for each extension or one process that loads all extensions all together?

Comment: Extensions are also isolated by separate processes

Comment: Thank you. I hope I get that thing done, does not seem to be easy.